# Catch All redux-little-router

Tags: reactjs

How can I do a catch-all with `redux-little-router` ? I need a route which catches all wrong urls.

I tried this yet:

```
<Fragment forRoute="/*">
    <DashboardView />
</Fragment>
```

or

```
<Fragment forRoute="*">
    <DashboardView />
</Fragment>
```

Also found:

```
<Fragment forNoMatch></Fragment>
```

But this also does not seem to work.

Any ideas ? Thank your for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display `DashboardView` on wrong url, try adding `<Fragment forNoMatch>...content goes here...</Fragment>` right after your other `Fragment`s

```
<Fragment forNoMatch>
  <DashboardView />
</Fragment>
```

Check out the example here in [the official docs](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router/blob/master/demo/client/demo.js#L79)

Comment: You are right. That were my exact same thoughts but this does not seem to work. Do you have an idea why ?

Comment: @Coder949 check out the link : https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router/blob/master/demo/client/demo.js#L79
In the example `<Fragment forNoMatch />` is nested in root Fragment:  `<Fragment forRoute="/" className={styles.container}>` . That may cause the issue in your case, but I'm still not sure yet. If you could provide me more detailed example...